# Azure Functions 2.x keep throwing catched exceptions

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-2.1

In my Azure Functions 2.x Project, i have a part of an Function, a `try-catch` block without `finally`, that more or less look like this.

```
Dictionary<string, int> varDict = null;
Tuple<string, DateTime> varTupl = null;
try
{
    varDict = await Core.GetDict(lcLat.Value, lcLong.Value);
    varTupl = await Core.GetTupl(lcLat.Value, lcLong.Value);
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    ae.Flatten().Handle(ex =>
    {
        // `log` is an ILogger, the standard Azure Functions passed param
        log.LogError(ex, ""); // Writes the ex's error
        Debug.WriteLine(""); // Writes the ex's error
        // the written content is ommited for readability sake
        // But will be shown below
        return true;
    });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Does exactly like Handle() Does
}
if(varDict != null && varTupl != null)
{
    // The Code won't go here, and always return HTTP 500 Instead
}
else
{
    // Here neither
}
```

The `Run` method itself is an `async Task<IActionResult>`, with `Core` as a `static public` class containing `GetDict()` and `GetTupl()` methods, each of them are also an `static async Task<T>` with their respective `T` return type and both doesn't have any `try-catch` block, only `using` (which are not supposed to throw any exceptions, right ?)

[image: Printed out, it means the Exception is handled correctly right ?]

The problem is, even though (i assume) the exceptions raised then bubbled up into my `try-catch` block, even with my `catch` block running printing the exception with my formatting from `catch` block, as shown in the screenshot ,my Azure Functions keep returning HTTP Error 500, skipping the rest of the code after the `try-catch` block

What i have tried

1. Disable 'Just My Code' debugging options in my Visual Stuido 2017
2. Adding `AggregateExceptions`, before this it's only catching for `Exception`
3. Flatten the AggregateException before `Handle()` it

Is this common on local development environment, or it's just me handling everything incorectly ?

Also, the output window keep printing out something like this
[image: Even though being thrown the host is keep running - Part 1]
and this
[image: Even though being thrown the host is keep running - Part 2]
even in idle state (while the HTTP endpoint isn't being invoked, just run in debug mode, idly waiting for invocation)
are these something that i have to concerned about ? are those even related with my problem